# jquery ui dialog stopped working - gives error "cannot call method 'mouseover' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have been using jQuery UI dialog boxes in my app, and all was well until today when I tried to open a dialog, and nothing happened.  In the console, was:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'mouseover' of undefined** - jquery-ui.js, line 162

and

**GET data: undefined (undefined)** - this had no line number, in Chrome, it just said "data:".

The code in jquery-ui.js that throws the error is in the resizable code:

```
this._handles.mouseover(function(){...});
```

My code for calling the dialog is:

```
$('.popup-trigger').click(function(){
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).dialog({
        width:650,
        minWidth:500,
        minHeight:250,
    });
    return false;
});
```

Where the href attribute of .popup-trigger elements is something like "#dialog".  This code was working fine until today.

I've done lots of work on the app since the time when it was last working properly, so I can't identify a single thing that has changed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  What is this error

Edit - after another look, I've discovered that this error only happens the FIRST time you click the button.  The second click successfully brings up the dialog with no errors.

Comment: The comma after minHeight shouldn't be there.  I can't say if that is causing it, but you should not have a comma after your last setting.

Comment: @jefffan24 is right, this can cause an error because when you use a comma, the parser will expect another property

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that wasn't the problem, though.  Removing the comma didn't fix it.

Comment: Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net) that repro's the error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got the exact same problem today.

Spend about one hour debugging my code and ends up finding that one of my custom function has a name conflict with jquery.ui function. In my case, the conflicting name is 'disableSelection'.

Hope it help in your case.

Comment: Amazing, I have exactly the same named function, 'disableSelection'.  That was the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: I've found that rearranging the order that my JS files have been included fixed the problem.  The code with the custom function disableSelection in is now after jQuery and before jQuery UI, and the problem has disappeared.